# Querystring doesn't stringify properly in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my question,

this is my string:

```
    var body = {
        message: "Hello",
        properties: [
            { text: 'Link Test 1', href: 'http://hei.it'},
            { text: 'Link Test 2', href: 'http://hei.it/rai1'},
        ],
        actions: [
            { name: 'Shawn', link: 'http://hu.com'}
        ]
    };
```

If I use

```
querystring.stringify(body);
```

I get back

```
 message=Hello&properties=&properties=&actions=
```

Is querystring bugged or am I wrong?

Comment: Given that `querystring.stringify()` is intended to output a query string, how would you expect it to handle nested objects? JSON is a string format that can handled nested data, but query strings don't.

Comment: but when I do a facebook request, i need to send nested objects

Comment: When someone does not know how things works and ask questions why should he be penalised with a vote down??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing whoever did thought that your question was unclear since you didn't describe your expected or desired output. Unfortunately though it's a fact of life on StackOverflow that some people downvote without any good reason (e.g., you'll see 100% correct answers downvoted without an explanatory comment) - I try not to take it personally when it happens to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found a library called node-qs that outputs:

message=Hello&actions[0][name]=Shawn&actions[0][link]=http%3A%2F%2Fhei.com